# Creating a network keyspace using Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I'm having problems creating a keyspace using the network topology.

Code:

```
// The Astyanax context I'm using
AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster("Test Cluster")
    .forKeyspace("NetworkKS")
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE))
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
    .setPort(9160)
    .setMaxConnsPerHost(10)
    .setInitConnsPerHost(1)
    .setSeeds("127.0.0.1:9160"))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();

// A different method takes the above context as a keyspace parameter
keyspace.createKeyspace(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("strategy_options", ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("us-east", "3")
            .put("eu-west", "3")
            .put("replication_factor", "1").build())
            .put("strategy_class", "NetworkTopologyStrategy").build());
```

I know it seems pointless creating a networkstrategy keyspace for one node, but this is just a test, once I get it working I'll add another Cassandra instance to the seeds.

The error is:

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl - TransportException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=42(42), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl - TransportException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=42(42), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
Jan 27, 2013 4:42:39 PM smail.cli.astyanax.Schema createNetworkKeyspace
SEVERE: null
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TransportException: TransportException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=42(42), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:197)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:27)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:248)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.createKeyspace(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:545)
    at smail.cli.astyanax.Schema.createNetworkKeyspace(Schema.java:121)
    at smail.cli.test.SchemaCreationTest.createNetKS(SchemaCreationTest.java:21)
    at smail.cli.test.SchemaCreationTest.runTest(SchemaCreationTest.java:50)
    at smail.cli.Main$1.run(Main.java:48)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Astyanax, but I'll note that creating keyspaces and columnfamilies programatically is a good way to get in trouble until Cassandra 1.2: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/new_features#concurrent-schema-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to create such a keyspace, if you first update your [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) configuration. You have to update `cassandra-topology.properties` in your node configuration, to tell either a default settings or describe you data centers and racks. The default content of the file is self explanatory.

After that is setup properly, you can properly create your keyspace. But it is better to follow the advice of [jbellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130168/jbellis), to not create the keyspace from code.